# How to parse XML in ASP/vbscript?

Tags: javascript, xml, asp-classic, vbscript

I have a result string with the following structure

```
<items>
    <item>
       <id>
```

I must iterate through down to id and I have some other tags there also. 
I really don't know how to do it in vbscript. And I would like to have all id:s returned in an array.

Is there not really a method like this:

```
Dim doc
Dim thumbArray
Set doc = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
doc.loadXML(searchresponse) 
thumbArray = doc.getElementsByTagName("id") 

for each tt in thumbArray
 Response.Write(tt & "<br>") 
next
```

Especially this:

```
getElementsByTagName("id")
```

Specifically I would like to do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
window.onload = function() {
    var content = document.getElementById("content"); 
    var ids = content.getElementsByTagName("thumbnail"); 
    var pics = document.getElementById("pics"); 
    var tts = []; 
    for(var i=0;i<ids.length;i++)
    {
        tts.push("<li>+ ids[i].innerHTML + </li>"); 
    }
    pics.innerHTML = tts.join(""); 


}
</script>
```

Comment: You've shown us some client side javascript but I'm guessing you actually want to do this server side.  Which isn't clear is what is inside an id element, would that be html mark up?  If so is it in escaped or CDATA form or is it well formed XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
Set thumbArray = doc.getElementsByTagName("id") 

for index = 0 to thumbArray.Length
    Response.Write(thumbArray[index].nodeValue & "<br>") 
next
```

Take a look at [this](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_nodes_info.asp).

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've worked with Vb Script but this should get you started.

```
Dim doc
Dim xmlString
Dim nodes
Dim idArray

Set doc = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
doc.loadXML xmlString

Set nodes = doc.selectNodes("items/item/id")

idArray = Array()
Redim idArray(nodes.length)

For i = 0 To nodes.length
    idArray(i) = nodes(i)
Next
```